# How can I get a file size before upload file in IE?

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, size, html4

I'm trying to get a file size before upload file in IE without ActiveX or like this.

I already read lots of questions and answers and they said it is impossible.

However, I found that Plupload which is jquery file upload library,

can get a file size in IE 7+ without AcviceX or Ajax submit to a server.

Have any clue to get a file size in IE7+ or how Plupload can get a file size?

Comment: As far as I know they use `Flash` , `Silverlight`, `HTML4` (presumably an `iframe` based upload) or `HTML5`. http://www.plupload.com/examples/runtimes

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />

$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
  alert(this.files[0].size);

});
```

Try with Above Code

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this answer, but your code won't work in `IE 7-9` as those browsers do not support `HTML5` `FileReader API`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader